# how to create multi store on live server in magento

Tags: php, magento

i have installed magento 1.4 on live server now i want to create my online multi store .can any body tell me how can i do it..to make my multi store live on server....thanks

Answer (score 1):

I found these 2 links very useful for setting up multi stores:
http://www.crucialwebhost.com/blog/how-to-setup-multiple-magento-stores/
http://blog.baobaz.com/en/blog/setting-up-magento-with-multiple-websites-or-stores/

Answer (score 0):

First create website/store/store views structure in Admin/Manage Stores
Then for each website server (or if the websites are under the main url like www.test.com/website1) create directory website1 on the server, copy to it .htaccess and index.php file. In the index.php change last line Mage::run('WEBSITE1CODE','website');

Answer (score 0):

Magento Step By step
Go to Admin panel

Add Root Category
Go to Catalog->Manage Categories

Click Add Root Category from left Panel

Ente Name as Theater Root
Is Active -Yes
URL key -theater_root
In Display Setting panel

Is Anchor Yes (To display the category in the Menu )
Click Save Category Button

Add a new Website/Store/Store View
Go to System->manage Stores

Click Create Website

Name Theater-1
Code theater_1
Click Save Website

Click Create store

Select Theater-1 from drop down against Website
Name - store1_theater_1
select Root category as Theater Root
Click Save Store Button at top.

Click Create Store View

Select Store Name from the drop down against the Store
Name -English Store View
Code -eng_store1_theater_1
Status -Enabled
Click Save store View
Now create a folder named theater_1 inside www/magento
copy index.php and .htaccess into the new folder
in index.php Change
$compilerConfig = '/includes/config.php';
into
$compilerConfig = '../includes/config.php';
and
$mageFilename = '/app/Mage.php';
into
$mageFilename = '../app/Mage.php';
and
Mage::run($mageRunCode, $mageRunType);
to
Mage::run('theater_1', 'website');
in .htaccess

## RewriteBase /magento/

into

## RewriteBase /magento/theater_1/

Go to System->Configuration

Select Theater-1 in Current Configuration Scope
Go to Web tab under General at left panel

change Base URL to http:// yourdomain .com / magento /theater_1 /
for Unsecure and Secure
Click Save Config Button.
Now the new URL to the new website is http:// yourdomain .com /magento /theater_1 /

Answer (score 0):

it`s very simple just copy two files in your magento root. and paste where you want (mysite.com) folder

That files are .htaccess.sample and index.php.sample

rename two files to .htaccess and index.php

open **index.php** and edit .

```
$mageFilename = MAGENTO_ROOT . '/app/Mage.php';
```

to

```
$mageFilename = '/root/mysite/app/Mage.php';
```

**Edit this two lines**

```
/* Store or website code */
$mageRunCode = isset($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE']) ? $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE'] : '';

/* Run store or run website */
$mageRunType = isset($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE']) ? $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE'] : 'store';
```

if you set $mageRunType this as 'store'
you must set $mageRunCode this as 'store code'